# Fatal error в цикле, задача fizz buzz

Tags: php, массивы, условия

`$handle = file("E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\php6\source.txt"); //фай содержит 3 значения, к примеру 3, 6, 120
$handleInt = array_map("integer", $handle); //приведение к int
$arrResult = range(1, $handleInt[2]);

function integer ($a){
    return (integer)$a;
} //костыль для приведения элементов $handle к int

function fizzBuzz ($a, $b){
    if (!($a % $b[0]) && !($a % $b[1])){//fatal error здесь
       return "FB ";
    } elseif (!($a % $b[0])) {
        return "F ";
    } elseif(!($a % $b[1])){
        return "B";
    } else return $a;
}

print_r($arrResult);
array_map("fizzBuzz", $arrResult, $handleInt);

?> </code>`

### Задача fizz-buzz:

Есть три числа которые программы принимает из файла. Первое число называется fizz, второе называется buzz. До третьего необходимо досчитать от единицы. Считая, надо выводить число. Если число кратно fizz - надо выводить F вместо числа. Если число кратно buzz - надо выводить B вместо числа. Если число кратно и fizz и buzz, надо выводить FB. И так - пока не будет достигнуто третье введенное число.

Пример условия и результата:
Введены числа 2, 5, 18
Вывод должен быть таким:
1 F 3 F B F 7 F 9 FB 11 F 13 F B F 17 F

### Вывод в консоли:

C:\Users\Максим>php E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\php6\index.php
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\php6\index.php:12

Stack trace:

#0 [internal function]: fizzBuzz(1, 1)

#1 E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\php6\index.php(22): array_map('fizzBuzz', Array, Array)

#2 {main}
  thrown in E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\php6\index.php on line 12

Comment: @DimaKaukin пробовал, работает абсолютно одинаково.
Суть проблемы в том что при выполнении скрипта вылезает ошибка.
гугл говорит, что проблемма с переменными в условии, типа невозможно делить на ноль. Это наводит на мысли что я неправильно передаю параметры в функцию.

Answer (score 0):

В общем там не одна ошибка

Первое `array_map("fizzBuzz", $arrResult, $new_handle);` Массивы должны быть одинаковый длины поэтому не второй элемент, который равен 120, а `$arrResult = range(1, count($new_handle));`

Второе как и говорил не понятно, как приводиться к массиву

```
// $handleInt = array_map("integer", $handle); //приведение к int

// Warning: array_map(): Argument 
// 2 should be an array in /var/www/test.php/ind.php on line 4
```

Выдавало ошибку, как и говорил дожен быть массив поэтому

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php

К примерe я прочитал текст он равен `$handle = "3,6,120";`, делаем `explode`, `$new_handle = explode(",", $handle);`

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Тертья у тебя идет не понятно в самой функции, `$b[0] или $b[1]`, он делает перебор массивов и берет по значению, получается это integer, а не массив

Четвертое не уверен, но я не понял для чего `$a % $b`, это  остаток от деления, следовательно выдает число, а любое число >= 1 это true, соответсвенно всегда правиьно, оно должно равняться нулю `$a % $b == 0`, тогда ты проверяешь делиться это число или нет.

Итог ты сравнивывываешь не каждое число, поэтому могу только догадываться чего точно ты хотел сделать, но для этого тебе нужно делать цикл

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($new_handle) - 1 ; $i++) {
    echo fizzBuzz($arrResult, $new_handle, $i);
}
```

А третий параметр это индекс по массиву, а в функцию передаешь массивы

Окончательный результат

```
$handle = "3,6,120";
$new_handle = explode(",", $handle);

$arrResult = range(1, count($new_handle));

function fizzBuzz ($a, $b){
    if (! ($a % $b == 0) && !($a % $b == 0)){//fatal error здесь
       return "FB "; 
    } elseif (!($a % $b == 0)) {
        return "F "; 
    } elseif(! ($a % $b == 0) ) {
        return "B"; 
    } else return $a;
}


$t[] = array_map("fizzBuzz", $arrResult, $new_handle);

print_r($t);
```

Comment: Другое тогда, ты хочешь сравнивать каждое число или разные, то есть как и было $a[0] % b[1], если это так то array map никак не подходит

Comment: эта задача уже была решена с помощью цикла. Суть задания в том что нужно используя array map добиться результата.

Comment: моё решение ниже в комментарии =)

Answer (score 0):

Решение затаилось неглубоко, при передаче в array_map второго массива, $handleInt.
Вместо этого я объявил массив глобально в функции fizzBuzz.

Вот что получилось)

```
    $handle = file("E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\php6\source.txt");
    $handleInt = array_map("integer",$handle);
    $arrResult = range(1, $handleInt[2]);
    function integer ($a){
        return (integer)$a;
    }
    function fizzBuzz ($a){
        global $handleInt;

        if (!($a % $handleInt[0]) && !($a % $handleInt[1])){
           return "FB ";
        } elseif (!($a % $handleInt[0])) {
            return "F ";
        } elseif(!($a % $handleInt[1])){
            return "B";
        } else return $a;

    }

    print_r (array_map("fizzBuzz",$arrResult));

    ?>
```